# Remove button on Rails page does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, ransack

I have two Rails sites (Bargain Stock Funds and Doppler Value Investing) that use the Ransack gem.

In the Bargain Stock Funds search page (http://www.bargainstockfunds.com/funds), I should be able to remove the default criteria by pressing the "remove" buttons.  Unfortunately, the remove button does not work.

However, the remove button does work in the development environment.  For the life of me, I can't figure out why the remove button works in the local environment but not in the production environment.

I'm using a similar setup on my Doppler Value Investing search page (http://www.dopplervalueinvesting.com/stocks), but the remove button works in both the local environment and the production environment.

My questions:
1.  Is there a way to properly troubleshoot this?  Are there log files I need to look at?
2.  Could something about the PostgreSQL database be a problem?  I thought of this, but logging into WebFaction and looking around didn't uncover anything.  (For all I know, this is completely irrelevant to my issue.)
3.  How exactly does the remove button work in a search form?

The source code for my Bargain Stock Funds site is at https://github.com/jhsu802701/bsf .

The source code for my Doppler Value Investing web site is at https://github.com/jhsu802701/dvi .

Answer (score 0):

The Web Developer tools in Firefox (Tools -> Web Developer -> Debugger) revealed that the production environment of my Bargain Stock Funds site was using jQuery version 1.9.1 while Doppler Value Investing was using version 1.7.2.

It turned out that jQuery version 1.9.1 was being mandated by files in the public/assets directory in Bargain Stock Funds.  The Doppler Value Investing file had no public/assets directory.  So I removed the public/assets directory from Bargain Stock Funds, and the buttons work as expected.